# Data structure used for directory structure?

Tags: data-structures, directory, directory-structure

I'm making a program which the user build directories (not in windows, in my app) and in these folders there are subfolders and so on; every folder must contain either folders or documents. What is the best data structure to use? Notice that the user may select a subfolder and search for documents in it and in its subfolders. And I don't want to limit the folders or the subfolders levels.

Comment: Judging from the specification, a folder may not contain a mixture of folders and documents?  And you cannot have empty subfolders?  Please be precise.

Comment: Actually, one part says folders may not contain a mixture; another part suggests they might.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I do:

Every record in the database has two fields: ID and ParentID. IDs are 4-5 characters (Base36, a-z:0-9 or something similar). Parent IDs are a concatenation of the parent's complete structure...

So...

This structure:

```
Root
   Folder1
   Folder2
      Folder3
   Folder4
      Folder5
         Folder6
```

Would be represented like this:

```
ID     ParentID     Name

0000   NULL           ROOT
0001   0000           Folder1
0002   0000           Folder2
0003   00000002       Folder3
0004   0000           Folder4
0005   00000004       Folder5
0006   000000040005   Folder6
```

I like this structure because if I need to find all the files under a folder I can do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Folders WHERE ParentID LIKE '0000%' -- to find all folders under Folder1
```

To delete a folder and all its children:

```
DELETE FROM Folders WHERE ID='0004' AND ParentID LIKE '00000004%'
```

To move a folder and its children, you have to update all the records that use the same parent, to the new parent.

> And I don't want to linit the folders or the subfolders levels

An obvious limitation to this is that the number of subfolders are limited to the size of your ParentID field.

Comment: If I add the field "size" for each folders/documents, how to update the size for all parents?

Answer (score 7):

I can think of a few ways you could structure this, but nothing would beat the obvious:

**Use the actual file system.**

Comment: Modded down, but really, this is the only sane answer!

Comment: Why? Not intending to come across as flippant, my question is sincere.

Comment: what if someone wants to keep a snapshot in the memory so that IO are minimal and only for writes. What then ? ... Using actual file system is not an option for high performance systems.

Comment: If I could use the actual file system, then I'd use the actual file system. But I can't. I need to create a directory structure from information stored in a database and, if the structure changes, I need to store the changes in a database. The file structure itself is transient.

Answer (score 5):

I would look into using some sort of [tree data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure)

Comment: Your name appears on your comments. You don't need to sign them.

Comment: @bzlm: Absolutely right. I was just getting used to SO back then :-)

Answer (score 2):

I should recommend B+ Tree .... You can easily use indexing (page,folder etc ) and all .

[B+ Tree http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Btree.png](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Btree.png)

for more info :
http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/cs/340/reading/btree/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is specifically asking for a data structure but...

If you are using an object oriented language maybe you can use the composite design pattern which is ideally suited for this type of hierarchical tree like structure. You get what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most OO languages come with some sort of abstraction for the file system, so there is where I would start. Then subclass it if you need to.

I would expect directories as an array of objects which are directories or files, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use m-way tree data structure

Answer (score 0):

A flat list has its advantages, such as easier handling, and possibly smaller space usage. To avoid repetition, just sort your full paths, then store for each item (file or folder) by its name without path.

```
level:int name:string (+ other attributes such as mtime, size)
```

Items on the list are implicitly children of the preceding lower level entry. All contents of any directory are found in rows directly following it until lower level.

The OP structure becomes  (to omit root remove the row and decrement levels)

```
0  Root
1  Folder1
1  Folder2
2  Folder3
1  Folder4
2  Folder5
3  Folder6
```

As an alternative still, instead of level store for each entry how many next entries are inside it (possibly deeper in recursion). Makes it even easier to grab any folder recursively but makes the list hard to manipulate, so I don't like it. Easy enough with the levels:

```py
loc = []
targetlevel = None
for [level, name, attrs] in table:
  # Stop at end of directory
  if targetlevel is not None and level <= targetlevel:
    break

  # Construct path fragments in loc for a full path
  loc = loc[:level] + [name]
  fullpath = "/".join(loc)
  if fullpath == "path/to/search":
    targetlevel = level

  # If found, report back all items that belong to target
  if targetlevel is not None:
    yield fullpath, attrs
```